# how to match everything between a string and before next space

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

lets say I have the following string:

```
sdffsd sfdfi -ip 192.168.1.1 sdfdf ertret
```

I would like to extract "192.168.1.1" or any other valid ip address (four decimal numbers, each ranging from 0 to 255, separated by dots, e.g., 172.16.254.1)

It seems the easiest way to do this is match everything between the string "-ip " and before the next following space (the space between 192.168.1.1 and sdfdf).

I tried:

```
sed -e 's/-s \(.*\)[[:space:]]/\1/'
```

but it didn't work

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?  Computer blew up?  Error message?  Got a different string than you expected?

Comment: Will the text before the IP address be the same length every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, your question is "How do I extract from string '-ip ' to next space?". Following commands answers that.

`sed -e 's/^.*-ip \([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/'`

It works by essentially saying "any amount of non-space chars": `[^ ]*`

`$ echo "sdf sfdi -ip 192.168.1.1 sdf eret" | sed -e 's/^.*-ip \([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/'`
`192.168.1.1`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming GNU `grep`:

```
$ echo 'sdffsd sfdfi -ip 192.168.1.1 sdfdf ertret' | grep -oE '[0-9.]+'
192.168.1.1
```

And to limit that to only valid IP addresses, so strings with 4 sets of digits separated by `.` and where none of those are over 255 (I'm not dealing with `<0` since the `-` will not have been matched in the first place):

```
$ echo 'sdffsd sfdfi -ip 192.168.1.1 sdfdf ertret' | grep -oE '[0-9.]+' | 
    awk -F. '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(NF!=4||$i>255){next}}}1;'
192.168.1.1
```

Comment: I was also thinking about using `awk` to golf the bytecount for the 4xsmallint check, instead of using a regexp like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37412592/5208540 . You beat me to it, +1

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
echo 'sdffsd sfdfi -ip 192.168.1.1 sdfdf ertret' | grep -oE "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget `sed`. This is how you extract likely IP(v4) addresses:

```
egrep -o '\b([0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?\.){3}[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?\b'
```

To get absolutely only valid IP addresses (i.e., no numbers above 255), pipe the above command into:

```
egrep -v '([3-9][0-9][0-9]|2[6-9][0-9]|25[6-9])'
```

Comment: The question explicitly asks for extractions of _valid_ IP addresses.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Fixed!

Comment: Your `egrep` rules out a whole lot of valid IP addresses though. To take a rather obvious example: `echo 192.168.1.1 | egrep -v '([3-9]..|2[6-9].|25[6-9])'`. Remember that `.` means "match any character" and that includes a `.`, so `[3-9]..` will happily match `92.1`.

Comment: @terdon Fixed!!